# PostgreSQL WHERE IN Clause

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to use split_part in **WHERE IN** clause of PostgreSql like below. Here **Objcode** is of type small int and **objection** may be like `1374,824,480,3287,3286%Custom objection`
But the query is returning null in abj column

```
SELECT o.objection, 
TO_CHAR(o.obj_redate,'DD-MM-YYYY') AS objection_date, o.srno,
(SELECT string_agg(objtype,'<br/>') FROM objection_t 
WHERE objcode IN (split_part(o.objection,'%',1))) as obj
FROM objection_history o
```

**objection_history**

```
**fil_no**    **objection**                **obj_date**
  1          1,2,4%some custom obj          2017-01-01
  2          5,6,300%nsnvnv                 2017-01-02  
  3          5                              2017-01-02
```

**Objection_t**

```
    **objcode**                 **objtype**
         1                     objection name
         2                      vjlbhjdhbldhb
         3                      bgbrbgrbnrb
```

Comment: We'd need at least table definitions, sample data and the expected output.

Comment: i have edited my question,  please check

Comment: Storing multiple values as comma separated strings is a really bad idea. Even more so if you mix different types

Comment: It would be more prudent to change the table and add a new column to put that `%` part in, because you're mixing two data types in one column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your query essentially results in passing a **single** string constant to the `IN` operator:

```
WHERE objcode IN ('1374,824,480,3287,3286')
```

Once you have removed the `%Custom objection` from the input you need to convert that single string value to multiple values. The easiest way is probably to convert that to an array.

```
WHERE objcode = ANY ( string_to_array(split_part(o.objection,'%',1), ',')::smallint[] )
```

`string_array` returns a `text[]` so you need to cast that to proper integer array.

---

Storing comma separated values like that in a column is a **really** bad design choice. If possible you should normalize your data model